# How to select rows in a csv file beased on the lenght?

Tags: python, list, csv, for-loop, if-statement

I'm trying to select the rows based on their length. Some of the rows in my csv file have 5 items, some have 20 items and some have 40. I want to collect all the rows if their lenght is between 24 and 34. So I tried below code:

```
my_path = r'c:\data\FF\Desktop\my_files' 

for file in os.listdir(my_path):
    path_file = os.path.join(my_path, file)
    with open(path_file, 'r') as output:
        reader = csv.reader(output, delimiter = ',')
        read = [row for row in reader if row] 
        for row in read:
            if len(row) > 24 or len(row) < 34:
                if row[9] == '3080':
                    print(row[0] + ',' + row[24] + ',' + row[25] + ',' 
                          + row[26] + ',' + row[27] + ',' + row[28] + ',' + row[29]
                          + ',' + row[30] + ',' + row[31] + ',' + row[32] + ',' + row[33] + ','
                          + row[34])
```

I receive the following error:

```
  File "C:\data\FF\Desktop\Python\PythongMySQL\untitled2.py", line 15, in <module>
    if row[9] == '3080':

IndexError: list index out of range
```

I expect to get several rows with a lenght between 24 and 34.

Comment: Use `and` not `or` when checking length. All rows qualify with `or`

Comment: @MarkTolonen I changed `or` to and `and` received the following error:    ` + row[34])

IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: That would require a length 35 row.

Comment: @MarkTolonen still the same error...

Comment: Or make it the pythonic `if 24 < len(row) < 34 :` and then once you made sure the line has a length < 34, the highest index you could (possibly) access is 32.

Comment: What if your row is length 25? Your indices assume a minimum row length.

Comment: instead of printing like `print(row[0] + ',' + row[1] + ','...` please use `print(row[1], row[2],.., sep=',')`

Comment: @MarkTolonen If my row is 25 I print it. Im still receieving the same error.

Comment: Because you are trying to print columns that don’t exist.

Comment: @MarkTolonen so you are saying column 34 doesnt exist?

Comment: That’s what the error message means. If you have a length 25 row how can you access `row[34]`?

Comment: For your logic to work, you must have at least 35 rows.

Comment: @SeyiDaniel no thats not what I want. I want rows between 24 and 34 long.

Comment: what is `if len(row) > 24 or len(row) < 34:` ? this wll be true for len =0,1,2,3...infinity

Comment: List indices are 0-based, your conditions give length 25 to 33 and you try to print columns that don’t exist in all those cases.

Comment: You need `and` not `or`

Comment: @MarkTolonen so how does it need to look like?

Comment: `if 24 <= len(row) <= 34: print([row[0]] + row[24:])`. Slicing won’t error if the columns don’t exist.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I dont want all the rows I want just the rows I showed above

Comment: I’m sure you’ll figure it out. You’ve given no data so I can’t give you a precise answer.

Comment: can we private chat?

Comment: Sure, I've posted an answer but start a chat if you need more help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example with data rows varying from 20-39 in length.  Only rows between 24 and 34 in length with column 9 == 3080 will print:

**input.csv**

```
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,3080,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,3080,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,3080,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,3080,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,3080,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,3080,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,3080,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38
```

**test.py**

```py
import csv

with open('input.csv','r',newline='') as f:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    for row in r:
        if 24 <= len(row) <= 34:
            if row[9] == '3080':
                print(','.join([row[0]] + row[24:]))
```

**Output:**

```
0,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31
0,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32
0,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33
```

Comment: Why are the rows `34` and `38` not being printed out?

Comment: 0-34 is length 35 and 0-38 is length 39, outside 24-34 length.  I get the impression you haven't explained your requirements well if this is confusing you

Comment: True. Gotcha. Thank you.  Can you upvote my question pls?

Answer (score -1):

As you said, you expect a length between 24 **and** 34, so you must update that condition as follow:

```py
my_path = r'c:\data\FF\Desktop\my_files' 

for file in os.listdir(my_path):
    path_file = os.path.join(my_path, file)
    with open(path_file, 'r') as output:
        reader = csv.reader(output, delimiter = ',')
        read = [row for row in reader if row] 
        for row in read:
            if len(row) >= 24 and len(row) <= 34:
                if row[9] == '3080':
                    print(row[0] + ',' + row[24] + ',' + row[25] + ',' 
                          + row[26] + ',' + row[27] + ',' + row[28] + ',' + row[29]
                          + ',' + row[30] + ',' + row[31] + ',' + row[32] + ',' + row[33] + ','
                          + row[34])
```

Note the operators update. This small change will ensrure you to have rows within `24 - 34` as you expect.

Comment: @E.Mancebo yes, still receiving the same error.